# Admob integration in an ios 8 app using swift

Tags: swift, admob, ios8

Is there anyone who got successful in integrating admob into ios 8 app using swift? 
Please share how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this link for googleAd in swift

https://github.com/goldenfiredo/Swift_GoogleAd

Comment: The link you provided is a very good example to integrate AdMob into your App. But I have spent 4 hours straight just to stop the compiler from denying my GAD Delegates (GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate). I had copied the code from the link above and pasted into my code, but then I spent 4 hours just to see that I had to go to > Build Settings >  Swift Compiler Code Generation > Objective C Bridging header > Add "your physical path to the bridging_header_file.h" . This did the job, I just wanted others to know this has to be done so that they do not face the difficulty I faced.

Comment: i am new to ios development.  and i make my first app with swift in ios. please give explain the above method that you have discuss above @Samir

Comment: here is the tutorial about what Samir said :https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but I found that I could not get the app to validate with the way that that repo uses that Ramesh shared.

I have just made a small repo for a demo purpose. I added the GoogleMobileAds.framework instead - see [here](https://github.com/Maccle415/SwiftAdmob)

Hope that helps if you battled like I did with not getting your app to validate.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmYekJEL7Q4&feature=iv&src_vid=_15_OmvJU2U&annotation_id=annotation_1073839571) video shows you how to make a banner AdMob in your app using SWIFT for iOS 8, i personally used it in a game.
While the video is only for apps but it works exactly the same in case of a game